# Azure Cloud Service stuck

Tags: azure

I have one Azure Cloud Service with a production deployment and a staging deployment.

I can upgrade, stop, delete, ... the production deployment but I cannot do any action on staging one. Says:

> Windows Azure is currently performing an operation with xxxxx on this deployment that requires exclusive access.

I waited the entire weekend and the problem persist. If I check on my Operation logs I can see that trace:

```
    <SubscriptionOperation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <OperationId>xxxxxxxx</OperationId>
    <OperationObjectId>/xxxxxxxx/services/hostedservices/fxcalendar/deployments/xxxxxxxx</OperationObjectId>
    <OperationName>DeleteDeploymentBySlot</OperationName>
    <OperationParameters xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagement">
        <OperationParameter>
            <d2p1:Name>subscriptionID</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Value>xxxxxxxx</d2p1:Value>
        </OperationParameter>
        <OperationParameter>
            <d2p1:Name>serviceName</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Value>xxxxxxxx</d2p1:Value>
        </OperationParameter>
        <OperationParameter>
            <d2p1:Name>deploymentSlot</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Value>Staging</d2p1:Value>
        </OperationParameter>
    </OperationParameters>
    <OperationCaller>
        <UsedServiceManagementApi>true</UsedServiceManagementApi>
        <UserEmailAddress>Unknown</UserEmailAddress>
        <SubscriptionCertificateThumbprint />
        <ClientIP>xxxxxxxx</ClientIP>
    </OperationCaller>
    <OperationStatus>
        <ID>xxxxxxxx</ID>
        <Status>Failed</Status>
        <HttpStatusCode>409</HttpStatusCode>
        <Error>
            <Code>ConflictError</Code>
            <Message>Windows Azure is currently performing an operation with x-ms-requestid xxxxxxxx on this deployment that requires exclusive access.</Message>
        </Error>
    </OperationStatus>
    <OperationStartedTime>2013-11-04T09:04:37Z</OperationStartedTime>
    <OperationCompletedTime>2013-11-04T09:04:38Z</OperationCompletedTime>
</SubscriptionOperation>
```

I don't know how to restore the Staging deployment. Only walkarround I can think is creating a new Cloud service and change DNS.

Comment: I faced a lot of issues with Cloud Services during last week. I could not perform a SWAP, and other things. I moved to a datacenter in Europe and now it's working. In azure dashboard, everything looks working fine. Try move to another datacenter. If the problem still persist, try to open a ticket with azure support.

Comment: I cannot simply move all the deployments (more than 20) from one hosting to another one :) but thanks 4 the hint

Comment: Well, "delete deployment" should always just work. If it doesn't you should just open a support ticket.

Comment: Solved. I waited an entire week for that, but I finally did it 1 hour ago :)

Comment: @ Jordi. Please share how you did it with the community

Comment: just worked without any action. Weird, isn't it?

Comment: we have been facing it a lot since yesterday. Any pointers on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue - the only we found around it is by **deleting** the Cloud Service entirely and re-creating it. Neither **Re-Imaging** or **Update** enabled us to restore integration with new deployments. The instance was working just fine, but we could not interact with it for deploying new updates.

***Note**: Be sure you have your security certificates (pfx) somewhere as you will need to re-upload them.*

#### Error Message - Trying to delete Cloud Service Instance

> Windows Azure is currently performing an operation with x-ms-requestid xxxxxxxx on this deployment that requires exclusive access.